# Synonym Analyzer mapping gives "Failed to install template" error

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 6.7 with this mapping that runs well :

```
"settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "normalizer": {
                "lowercase": {
                "type": "custom",
                "filter": ["lowercase"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
 "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "properties": {
              "primarytrades": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties" :{
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256,
                                    "normalizer": "lowercase"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                     }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
```

This is working well and I am trying to add Synonym Analyser to this field mapping. I am deleting an index and creating new index and I get error "Failed to install template". Here is my code :

```
"settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "normalizer": {
          "lowercase": {
            "type": "custom",
            "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [ "my_synonyms" ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "my_synonyms": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": "piping, plumbing",
            "updateable": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "properties": {
               "primarytrades": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties" :{
                        "name": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                             "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256,
                              "normalizer": "lowercase"
                             },
                             "keyword_analyzered_field": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "search_analyzer": "synonym_analyzer" 
                             }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
            }
```

Can anyone guide me why my mapping is failing and how can I implement this functionality successfully?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a mapper parsing exception, which states that

> "analyzer on field [keyword_analyzered_field] must be set when
> search_analyzer is set"

**`"search_analyzer"` can be included in the index mapping definition of a field, only if the `"analyzer"` is defined for that particular field.**

Modify your index mapping as

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "synonym_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "my_synonyms"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": "piping, plumbing",
          "updateable": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "primarytrades": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "normalizer": "lowercase"
                },
                "keyword_analyzered_field": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analzer": "synonym_analyzer",            // note this
                  "search_analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You saved my day! Tested this through Kibana and it's working! Mapping is created.

Comment: @@ESCoder  I made this changes to the project's json mapping file and ran the whole ETL process with new mapping but surprisingly mapping on my Index is not updated. I see log files and looks like pipeline ran successfully. I am not sure why my mapping is not updated? Is there any other thing needs to be considered ?